# Can't properly setup vsftpd using MariaDB

Tags: ftp, debian, raspberrypi, vsftpd

**Goal**

My goal is to have an FTP server (vsftpd) installed to which I can add users / passwords to my MariaDB for verification.

I have been using this guide:
https://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-hosting-with-vsftpd-and-mysql-on-debian-squeeze
and a few others to try and fix my problems.

**Problem**

In trying to connect using FileZilla it states `ECONNREFUSED' Connection refused by server` so it seems that my server isn't even accepting the connection in the first place.

My packages I installed are: `vsftpd`, `libpam-mysql`, and `MariaDB`

If I am simply missing a package please let me know too as that may be an easy fix!

**MariaDB**

My MariaDB is definitely set up correctly as I can query it for other applications. I do have a database named vsftpd, table named accounts, and columns of id, username, password with two sample users in it.

I did run the following to give vsftpd permissions:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP ON vsftpd.* TO 'vsftpd'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'ftpdpass';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP ON vsftpd.* TO 'vsftpd'@'localhost.localdomain' IDENTIFIED BY 'ftpdpass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I left the password as ftpdpass just to try and get things running but will go back and change it later if I can actually get a process to install this correctly down.

**vsftpd**

My `/etc/vsftpd.conf` is as follows:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
nopriv_user=vsftpd
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
local_root=/home/vsftpd/$USER
user_sub_token=$USER
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
```

**libpam-mysql**

My `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` is as follows:

```
auth required pam_mysql.so user=vsftpd passwd=ftpdpass host=localhost db=vsftpd table=accounts usercolumn=username passwdcolumn=pass crypt=2
account required pam_mysql.so user=vsftpd passwd=ftpdpass host=localhost db=vsftpd table=accounts usercolumn=username passwdcolumn=pass crypt=2
```

As noted below I kept my password as ftpdpass for right now until I get a working solution

**Extra**

I did restart vsftpd after all of this but still get a refused connection. Perhaps more experienced users have a way for me to check what is wrong? By all means ask if I need to provide more information at all. All help is greatly appreciated!

Also note that this is running on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian / Debian 7 if that makes any difference. I just did a brand new install.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this. One thing to note for anyone in the future looking at this. If you ever want to see if vsftpd is actually running and listening run the following command:

```
netstat -tlpm
```

**You should see `vsftpd` in the list listening under port 21!**

If you do not then it is not listening / running. For me this was because my `/etc/vsftpd.conf` had something wrong in it. If vsftpd has a parameter incorrect (i.e. typed wrong) it simply will not run.  Either way my new `/etc/vsftpd.conf` is as follows:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
nopriv_user=vsftpd
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
local_root=/home/vsftpd/$USER
user_sub_token=$USER
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
pasv_enable=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

The key lines that I was missing were:

```
pasv_enable=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

This solved my issue to where I could connect.

**Different issue solved**

I wanted to add this note to anyone else having the same problems. After connecting successfully I wanted my users to have the ability to edit their home folder. In order to do this, my process for adding a new user is:

1. Insert username, password to my database:
   INSERT INTO accounts (username,pass) VALUES('newuser',PASSWORD('password'));

*Note it is important to use PASSWORD() around the password or connections will not work!

2. Create new directory for user and ensure that vsftpd has ownership to it

   `mkdir /home/vsftpd/newuser`

   `chown -R vsftpd /home/vsftpd`

   `chmod -R u+rX /home/vsftpd`
3. Now connecting as new user will work and have write / read access to home directory!